# How to make a discord.py bot add a reaction to its own message

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I am making a discord bot and I am trying to add a verify command where the person will use ".verify" then the bot will send me a dm with 2 reactions, a check mark, and an X. But I cant get the discord bot to add the reactions or give the role on the reaction of yes.

code:

```
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx):
  verifier = ctx.author
  jj = await client.fetch_user(270397954773352469)
  await ctx.send(f'{verifier}... Awaiting Verification, you will recieve a dm when you are verified')
  dm = await jj.send(f'{verifier.mention} is trying to be verified, do you know him/her?')
  await dm.add_reaction(':white_check_mark:')
  await dm.add_reaction(':no_entry_sign:')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try entering the unicode version of the emoji's, For example

```
await dm.add_reaction("✅")
await dm.add_reaction("")
```

Here is where you can find a lot of useful emojis: https://emojipedia.org/

You just copy them and paste them in your code, and they should turn into the discord version. I don't think it works with all emoji's though so keep that in mind

Comment: by the way, I recommend joining the discord.py discord server since they have help channels there

https://discord.gg/dpy